# Для чего сравнивать this и любой Object o?

Tags: java

Для чего сравнивать this, и любой Object o? В каких случая они могут оказаться равными?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было бы очень хорошо, если бы вы конкретизировали вопрос, а то остаётся только гадать о контексте. Подозреваю, что вас интересует один из этапов работы типовой реализации метода `equals`. Если так, то сравнивать `this` с аргументом стоит для случаев, когда вызывающий код сравнивает объект с сами собой.

```
public class Demo {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo one = new Demo();
        Demo two = one;

        if (one.equals(two)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я думал мы так сравниваем ссылки

Comment: @KrychunIvan так и есть. Если `equals` не переопределён, то сравниваются ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

> В каких случая они могут оказаться равными?

Когда это сравнение находится внутри метода объекта `o`.